# How to dynamically specify the file name for a datasource

Tags: javascript, xpages

On a custom control I want to bind the datasource to a database other than the current one. So I have selected the other option and selected the database from the list provided. All is well but I want this to be not dependent on the location of the database. I have created a profile document and stored the repID of the db I want to target and added this code to the Other option:

```
var repID = database.getProfileDocument("frmConfigProfile","").getItemValue("WFSRulesRepID")[0];
session.getDbDirectory(null).openDatabaseByReplicaID(repID).getFilePath();
```

This code returns the correct FilePath and Name, but the code fails when I try to open a document in the target DB. Do I need to specify the server as well as the filePath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add server name also. Here's an example where you just need to add your own file path logic:

```
<xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:
  var fileName = ...;
  return database.getServer() + "!!" + fileName
}]]></xp:this.databaseName>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. It seemed that from time to time the repID value would be null, so I created a sessionScope variable and stored the repID in it. Checked to see if the ss variable was set and if not get the value. This seems to have resolved the issue, without adding the server name, but I believe adding the server name will make it more bullet proof. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not use profile documents with xPages. In order to see new changes to the profile document the HTTP task needs to be restarted.

I would try and replicate the functionality of a profile document with some other functionality.

Will this only be updated by an admin?

As far as how to accomplish it I would use a custom control with a custom datasource to add the data if it was only going to be added by an admin with designer. If you are going to have an end user complete the data I could think of a few ways to accomplish it with a document/view.

Comment: The RepID would remain very static so If I stored the value in a regular Notes Document then load the values into an applicationScope variable would work then. And yes the values for the repIDs would probably be set at the time the database is started and it is highly unlikely that they would ever change and it would definitely be an Admin or Developer change. The end users would never see this.

Comment: I drove myself crazy with the profile document thing. Restarting HTTP is a deal killer for me so I had to find other options.

Comment: The "correct" way is to use an object in the application scope - can be a bean, a managed bean or a JS object. It should feature a "refresh" function. Then it doesn't matter if a lookup is involved (or other means) on first load.